# Errors while transforming points in an image after rotation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to transform points in an image after rotating it. So far the function works but when i try to run the function by looping over a list, i get error :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-5212c5d62ca8> in <module>
     31 #bb1 = [(45, 230), (283, 230),(283, 308),(45, 308)]
     32 for i in bb1:
---> 33     new_bb[i] = rotate_box(bb1[i], cx, cy, heigth, width)

IndexError: index 45 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

The code i use is:

```
def rotate_box(bb, cx, cy, h, w):  
new_bb = list(bb)                                                                                                                                                 
for i,coord in enumerate(bb):
    # opencv calculates standard transformation matrix                                                                                                            
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx, cy), -degree, 1.0)
    # Grab  the rotation components of the matrix)                                                                                                                
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])                                                                                                                                         
    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image                                                                                                            
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))
    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cx
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cy
    # Prepare the vector to be transformed 
    v = [coord[0],coord[1],1]
    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    calculated = np.dot(M,v)
    new_bb[i] = (int(calculated[0]),int(calculated[1])) 
    return new_bb 

h = 330
w = 335
cx = 167.5
cy = 167  
degree = 30  

new_bb = []
bb1 = np.array([[45, 230], [283, 230],[283, 308],[45, 308]])
#bb1 = [(45, 230), (283, 230),(283, 308),(45, 308)]
for i in bb1: 
    new_bb[i] = rotate_box(bb1[i], cx, cy, h, w)
```

It is taken from [Find [x,y] rotated coordinates locations in image [OpenCV / Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354804/find-x-y-rotated-coordinates-locations-in-image-opencv-python)

So the code works fine if i write lists like:

```
bb1 = [(45, 230)]
```

and change the last line to :

```
new_bb = rotate_box(bb1, cx, cy, h, w)
```

But if i write an entire list and dont change the last linbe like this

```
bb1 = [[45, 230], [283, 230],[283, 308],[45, 308]]
```

the error i get is :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-52-dbcc21beb4e6> in <module>
     31 bb1 = [[45, 230], [283, 230],[283, 308],[45, 308]]
     32 for i in bb1:
---> 33     new_bb[i] = rotate_box(bb1[i], cx, cy, h, w)


TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

when i change it to:

```
bb1 = [45, 230, 283, 230,283, 308,45, 308]
```

i get the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-51-6e6aae09f4f2> in <module>
     31 bb1 = [45, 230, 283, 230,283, 308,45, 308]
     32 for i in bb1:
---> 33     new_bb[i] = rotate_box(bb1[i], cx, cy, h, w)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

can anyone suggest  where i am going wrong ?

Comment: If you use a debugger or print statement, you will see that you aren't looping correctly.  Your values of i are not 1, 2, 3, 4..., they are 45, 230, 283, etc.  So bb1[i] is equal to bb1[45] on the first loop.  You probably want `for i in range(len(bb1))`.

Comment: @FiddleStix Thanks for the reply. Wit this i dont get any error, but then it just transforms the first two elements, i.e [45, 230] and rest are unchanged. It does not seem to loop over list